# Estimation of conditional sum of normal random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider $N$ i.i.d standard normal random variables $\varepsilon_i$, $i = 1, ... , N$.

Define $x_i = \omega\varepsilon_i +\mu$ , where $\mu$ is a known constant, but $\omega$ is constant and unknown.

I am given the following two observations:

$X = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$

$Y = \sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2$

How can I calculate the maximum likelihood estimators for $\omega$ and $Z$ given $(X , Y)$, defined as below?

$Z = \sum_{i=1}^N \varepsilon_i$

ADDENDUM:

Thank you kindly for your replies. I have been able to do some further work on the question, and I would like to know if the method I used is sensible.

Define $S^2 := \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_i (x_i - \bar x )^2$

Where $\bar x := \frac{1}{N}\sum_i x_i \equiv \frac{X}{N}$

Then we have $S^2 = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_i (x_i^2 -2x_i \bar x + \bar x^2 )=\frac{1}{N-1} (Y - \frac{1}{N}X^2 )$

We know that, being $S^2$ the sample variance of the $x_i$ which are $i.i.d.$ normally distributed, then $U:=\frac{N-1}{\omega^2}S^2 \sim \chi_{N-1}^2$ , i.e $U$ is a Chi-squared distribution with $N-1$ degrees of freedom. Additionally, $U$ is independent of $X$.

We can now compute the probability that $Z=z$ conditional on $(X,Y)$:

$P( Z=z | X=x , Y=y)=P\Biggl(\frac{X-N\mu}{\omega}=z\Biggl|X=x,U=\frac{1}{\omega^2}(y - \frac{1}{N}x^2 )\Biggr)=$

$=P\Biggl(\frac{(x-N\mu)^2}{\omega^2}=z^2\Biggl|\omega^2=\frac{1}{U}(y - \frac{1}{N}x^2 )\Biggr)=P\Biggl(U=\frac{z^2(y - \frac{1}{N}x^2 )}{(x-N\mu)^2}\Biggr)$

Here we need to estimate the value of $z$ for which the pdf of $U$ is maximized (as per the maximum likelihood method). For a Chi-squared distribution with $K$ degrees of freedom, that corresponds to $K-2$. Since here we have $K=N-1$, then we require

$N-3=\frac{z^2(y - \frac{1}{N}x^2 )}{(x-N\mu)^2}$

Finally, the required estimator is

$\hat Z = \frac{\sqrt{N-3}(X-N\mu)}{\sqrt{Y - \frac{1}{N}X^2}}$

Numerical simulations seem to agree with this answer, and the mean squared error between $Z$ and $\hat Z$ seems to be smallest using $\sqrt{N-3}$ as the root-integer multiplier of the above expression.

One question I have is the following (which I assume to be the true): do the random variables $X$ and $U$ need to be independent for the above process to be correct? Since we could have chosen a different Chi-squared random variable, for example $V=\sum_i \varepsilon_i^2$, which would have yielded a different result.

Answer (score 1):

For each $i$, $E(x_i)=\mu=\frac{E(X)}{N}$ and $E(x_i^2)=\omega^2+\mu^2=\frac{E(Y)}{N}=\nu$.  This leads to estimate for $\omega$ as $\sqrt{\nu-\mu^2}$

Because each $\epsilon_i$ is standard normal $E(Z)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I do not think it answers the question as I intended it. Suppose $N = 10, \mu = 1 , X = 30 , Y = 50$. What is the value of $Z$ which most likely produced the observed values of $(X , Y )$? The numbers have been made up on the spot, I am interested in the process, rather than the numerical answer to this specific case. Thanks again for your time

Comment: $X=\omega Z+N\mu$ while $Y=\omega^2\sum e_i^2 +2\mu Z- N\mu^2$.  How to extract $Z$ requires a way to estimate $\sum e_i^2$  (I suggest you check my derivations)  For sufficiently large $N$, an estimate would be $\frac{N}{N-1}$.

Comment: Error: estimate should be $N$ for large $N$.